# UIView not resizing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, xamarin.ios

For some strange reason, every new UIViewController I add into my project is not resizing according to the screen. 
As you can see here in Xcode I'm using Retina 3.5 Inch Full Screen and it's supposed to look like this.

[image: Xcode Interface Builder]

But in the iPhone the lower part of the screen is not being shown. This is what I see in a real iPhone 4.

[image: iPhone]

As you can see, the button in the inferior part of the screen is behind that white bar and I can't click it.

I've really tried everything and I don't know what I'm missing.
I'm also tagging Objective-C as this could be cross platform.

Comment: What version of iOS is running on the iPhone? Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Can yoo please do another screenshot with the view.backgroundColor set to something different to white?

Comment: iPhone is running iOS 7.1.2. The same as Simulator and yes, autolayout is activated

Comment: @LucaBartoletti I just changed the pictures

Comment: Ok, you can see that the view of your viewController is not properly resized. Can you give us more context? What are your viewControllers hierarchy?

Comment: This is the rootcontroller. Also if I enable the 4-inch simulator the white bar disappears and everything works smoothly.

Comment: Can you show the code where it is added as rootViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue thanks to Luca. I was using a component for a Menu Bar that made the screen not to resize properly to 3.5 inch. Removed it and now everything works.